# Reading text files from command prompt

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I want to be able to read text files from the command line. 
So what I'm trying to do is

1) ./a.out menu1.txt menu2.txt

And let the user choose how many files they want to read from so it could also be

2) ./a.out menu1.txt menu2.txt menu3.txt how do I do that?

```
menu1.txt 
hamburger 5.00
pizza 3.25
chips 2.50

menu2.txt
hamburger 2.00
pizza 2.35
chips 1.50

menu3.txt
hamburger 4.00
pizza 5.35
chips 0.50
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 #include <fstream>
 int main(int argc,  char *argv)
 {
  ifstream inStream; 

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

    String menu1 = *argv[i]; 
    String menu2 = *argv[i]; 
    String menu3 = * argv[i]; 
    cout << i << " " << endl;  

}
```

}

Comment: Okay. What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Then go for it and try reading the files :) - you have the loop ready

Comment: Your book should tell you how to use an `ifstream`. You do have a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/7455774), right?

Answer (score 0):

Function `main` provides the number of command line arguments and the argument values (including the name of the program itself):
With that, you can achieve what you want.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << "The name used to start the program: " << argv[ 0 ]
    << "\nArguments are:\n";
    for (int n = 1; n < argc; n++)
        std::cout << n << ": " << argv[ n ] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

For more details, confer, for example, [cppreference - main function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function). It explains, for example, that the "name of the program" could be an empty string:

> argv[0] is the pointer to the initial character of a null-terminated
>   multibyte strings that represents the name used to invoke the program
>   itself (or an empty string "" if this is not supported by the
>   execution environment)

Comment: Caveat: `std::cout << "The name used to start the program: " << argv[ 0 ]` is not entirely true. There will be an `argv[ 0 ]`, but it may be left blank.

Comment: @user4581301: Thanks for pointing that out. Adapted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it mostly done.

1. You have bad signature of your main - that shold be
   `int main(int argc, char** argv)`
   or
   `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`
2. I don't understand why you try to initialize `menu1`, `menu2` and `menu3` with the same argument.

You may store your file paths in some `std::vector<std::string>` for future use.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> filePaths;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        filePaths.emplace_back(argv[i]);
    }

    //...

    return 0;
}
```